# SQLite3 Update join not working

Tags: sqlite

I've tried everything I've seen here and other sites.  I'm beginning to think it's impossible to do a update join with SQLite3 (V 1.2.2) and SQLite (V 3.7.3).  I've been a MSSql Server developer for years.  SQLite is a different animal.  If I had Cursor capability in TSQL, I'd just handle it that way.  The query below is based on what has been suggested on several sites.  Here is my latest attempt that doesn't work.

```
update alertsettings
   set IP_Desc = (select temp_tbl.Import_Rec
                    from alertsettings,
                         temp_tbl
                   where temp_tbl.IPAddress = alertsettings.IPAddress)
```

This should update each record with the appropriate description connected to the matched IP based on examples I've seen.  All IP's are unique.  It does update, but updates all records have then same IP_Desc. Out of 576 records, it matches one record.  I'm not sure why it should work because there is no relationship with the current record being updated.  The "Select" joins in the "Select" not the "Update".

Thanks - Hostdad

Answer (score 0):

When you write `alertsettings.IPAddress`, the value is taken from the *innermost* table that matches the name `alertsettings`.
In your query, this is the the `alertsettings` in the inner `select`, which is independent from the record in the outer `update`.

You do not actually want a *join*, you want the subquery to just look up a single value from another table:

```
update alertsettings
   set IP_Desc = (select Import_Rec
                    from temp_tbl -- no second table here
                   where IPAddress = alertsettings.IPAddress)
```